# I want to use the htmlbody of a google sites page as a template for an email template, but I can't get it to find and replace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have been successful finding and replacing using a document as template, and can get the unmodified html into an email, but no luck in being able to find and replace content. This should be it, right? (I tried replaceText too, but assume it is a document thing)) I don't get an error message or anything, the script just continues on to the next steps, I just don't get any replacement.

```
var site = SitesApp.getPageByUrl(PageUrl);
var body = site.getHtmlContent();
body.replace("{%Organization%}", "ORGANIZATION")
```

Thanks
(the thing to be replaced (in this case {%Organization%} is within a table on the site if that matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following line:

```
body = body.replace("{%Organization%}", "ORGANIZATION");
```

The string `replace` function does not alter the original string. Instead, it returns a new string value. The code above will assign the new value to the original `body` variable.

For more information [see this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: That'll do it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

String.replace() is a valid method in Apps Script. I would look at the returned html to make sure your tags are correctly formatted to match your replace() case.